How does Yedora interact with face-down non-creature creatures?
Suppose that I have Yedora, Grave Gardener on board, as well as a face-down non-creature card which is, in its face-down state, some kind of creature (e.g. a manifest, morph, or mysterious creature).  That is, suppose that I have somehow managed to put a sorcery or land face-down as a creature (e.g. by manifesting dread).  When this non-creature creature dies, how does it interact with Yedora's ability?

Whenever another nontoken creature you control dies, you may return it to the battlefield face down under its owner’s control. It’s a Forest land.


Yedora's ability triggers and the card returns to the battlefield face down as a Forest land.
Yedora's ability only looks at what characteristics the card had on the battlefield when determining whether to trigger. The card was a creature permanent on the battlefield, so the ability triggers. This is mainly a consequence of rules 603.10 and 603.10a and rule 603.6c (with some clarification from rule 700.4):

603.10. Normally, objects that exist immediately after an event are checked to see if the event matched any trigger conditions, and continuous effects that exist at that time are used to determine what the trigger conditions are and what the objects involved in the event look like. However, some triggered abilities are exceptions to this rule; the game "looks back in time" to determine if those abilities trigger, using the existence of those abilities and the appearance of objects immediately prior to the event. The list of exceptions is as follows:

603.10a. Some zone-change triggers look back in time. These are leaves-the-battlefield abilities, abilities that trigger when a card leaves a graveyard, and abilities that trigger when an object that all players can see is put into a hand or library.

603.6c. Leaves-the-battlefield abilities trigger when a permanent moves from the battlefield to another zone, or when a phased-in permanent leaves the game because its owner leaves the game. These are written as, but aren't limited to, "When [this object] leaves the battlefield, . . ." or "Whenever [something] is put into a graveyard from the battlefield, . . . ." (See also rule 603.10.) An ability that attempts to do something to the card that left the battlefield checks for it only in the first zone that it went to. An ability that triggers when a card is put into a certain zone "from anywhere" is never treated as a leaves-the-battlefield ability, even if an object is put into that zone from the battlefield.
700.4. The term dies means "is put into a graveyard from the battlefield."

